# Time Machine Encryption Specs

Tags: macos, time-machine, encryption

I'm looking for specs on Time Machine (TM) encryption.

- Does TM encrypt before transmitting over network? (i.e. 128-bit AES)
- What level of file encryption does it store the files as? (i.e. 128-bit AES, 428-bit blowfish, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple documents it's cryptographic certifications online:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201159

From the [PDF for Crypto Officer on OS X 10.10](https://support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT205017/APPLEFIPS_GUIDE_CO_OSX10.10.pdf) (these documents and evaluations happen after the OS is released, so look for 10.11 crypto certifications mid-winter to early spring) it states that

> “FIPS Mode” is enabled all the time automatically without the need for installation, administration or configuration.
>
> FileVault 2, Kerberos, Keychain Services, Software Update Services, Time Machine, VPN, and 802.1X are all [FIPS 140-2 compliant](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips140-2/fips1402.pdf)

So, if you spend a lot of time reading those links - you'll see the the certification was done to Level 1 requirements. Nothing about Time Machine makes sense about network since it decrypts things to run. According to [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204837), the encryption used on disk is **XTS-AES 128 encryption**